# Replace space character with regular expression, php

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I am using the function `preg_replace('/[^0-9A-F]/', '', $string)` to accept only numbers and letters but at the moment is not filtering spaces, how can I include that into my reg expression? thanks

Comment: check [escape sequences](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php)

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_replace('/[^0-9A-F ]/', '', $string)
```

As a side note, you are only allowing capital letters from A to F. If you want all letters:

```
 preg_replace('/[^0-9A-Z ]/i', '', $string)
```

Comment: How about using `\s` to cover tabs as well? )

Comment: @raina77ow It depends on the string. For a username for instance I would not allow tabs, or newlines for a username. This is up to the OP.

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_replace('/[^0-9A-F\x20]/', '', $string)
```

Comment: Why would you use \x20 instead of \s or ' '? Just curious.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
preg_replace('/[^0-9A-F]/',( )'', $string)
```